# Login link from codegolf.xyz not working; redirecting to codegolf.xyz/users/https

Tags: support

I attempted to log in from the "Login" link on the StackExchange bar, and it just redirects to https://codegolf.xyz/users/https, which is a 404. I am able to login from http://codegolf.stackexchange.com, but not codegolf.xyz

I'm in Firefox on Linux (Ubuntu 15.10), here's the network tab from the devtools:

[image: Firefox devtools]
[image: full request headers]

I was able to reproduce in an Firefox private browsing tab, as well as Chromium, in both regular and incognito.

Comment: codegolf.xyz is a mirror provided by a user, not Stack Exchange: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9222/what-is-codegolf-xyz.

Comment: `codegolf.xyz` is not a Stack Exchange site. To login to the codegolf Stack Exchange, you need to go to codegolf.stackexchange.com

Comment: Aha! I was unaware of that, and that indeed does explain things.  Thanks, if one of y'all wants to note that as an answer I'll accept it, or we could flag this for close as "not pertaining to StackExchange" or, maybe, a dupe of the question @hichris123 linked.

Comment: (Appropriately, I didn't find the CodeGolf meta site, because the help menu doesn't work on codegolf.xyz either)

Comment: This is a scraper (illegal), they never really "work" properly since they just copy the raw contents of the sites.

Comment: @Sha I'd disagree that it's a dupe - sure, it's a scraper, but the answer to the dupe target is "report it", which isn't the answer here. The answer here is "use the real site".

Comment: @ArtOfCode this is still illegal scraper as far as I can tell. Maybe not malicious but also not legit. Only reason to not report it is that SE is already aware of it.

Comment: @Sha sure, you're totally right there. My point is that "report the scraper" isn't an answer to "why can't I log in".

Comment: @ArtOfCode so we can add another section there about such cases when SE already aware of it, and/or it's not malicious, and what to do in those cases. Still doesn't justify a separate question, in my opinion.